# Custom group "states" in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

There are essentially just two states for groups out-of-the-box: `hover` and `focus`

Simplified examples:

```html
<div class="group">
  <p class="group-hover:text-gray-900">foo</p>
  <p class="group-hover:text-gray-500">bar</p>
</div>
```

```html
<a class="group">
  <span class="group-focus:text-gray-900">foo</span>
  <span class="group-focus:text-gray-500">bar</span>
</a>
```

Ho to add custom states, so this is possible:

```html
<a class="group">
  <span class="group-foo-state:text-gray-900">foo</span>
  <span class="group-foo-state:text-gray-500">bar</span>
</a>
```

and with the custom state `foo-state` active

```html
<a class="group foo-state">
  <span class="group-foo-state:text-gray-900">foo</span>
  <span class="group-foo-state:text-gray-500">bar</span>
</a>
```

Essentially mimicking the `CSS` cascade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) or use same arbitrary variants since Tailwind 3.1.

> To support the group-* and peer-* versions of your own custom modifiers, register them as separate variants using the special :merge directive to ensure the .group and .peer classes only appear once in the final selector - [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#parent-and-sibling-states)

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('group-with-foo', ':merge(.group).foo &') // custom CSS
      addVariant('group-no-foo', ':merge(.group):not(.foo) &')
    })
  ],
}
```

`addVarinat` function is what creates new variant. First argument - variant name, should be unique. Second - any valid CSS as string (or function which should return string or an array of strings).

`&` sign points to an element with THIS custom variant. Your plugin SHOULD have either `&` or starts with `@` symbol otherwise it will not be valid.

```html
<a class="group">
  <span class="group-with-foo:bg-red-500">
    Parent has NOT `foo` class therefore I'm NOT red
  </span>
  <span class="group-no-foo:bg-red-500">
    Parent has NOT `foo` class but it doesn't matter (it has `group` though)
  </span>
</a>

<hr>

<a class="group foo">
  <span class="group-with-foo:bg-red-500">
    It is red because parent has BOTH `group` and `foo` class
  </span>
  <span class="group-no-foo:bg-red-500">
    Parent has `foo` class therefore I'm not red
  </span>
</a>
```

If you need to use arbitrary variants you need to pass same CSS as seconda argument, but instead of spaces you should use `_`. If your class has `_` sign, it must be escaped as `\_`

```html
<a class="group">
  <span class="[.group.foo_&]:bg-red-500">
    It is red because parent has BOTH `group` and `foo` class
  </span>
  <span class="[.group:not(.foo)_&]:bg-red-500">
    Parent has `foo` class therefore I'm not red
  </span>
</a>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cZ5ewP7xgW?file=config)

Comment: That's weird. Why isn't it mentioned in [this page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state) that we need to add the variants into the tailwind.configs BEFORE using it?

Comment: @maiakd not sure I understood you. It is a custom variant and it should be registered. Page you gave is about default group variants

Comment: when using custom arbitrary values in any other cases, we ain't registering nothing. Such as `text-[6rem]`, p-[1rem], so why are supposed to register it in this case? Besides in the page I linked, they are not saying we have to UNLESS we check the Plugins page

Comment: You're not supposed. Both cases are present in the answer. Register plugin or use arbitrary variants is just user preference